# WPF Collapsible Menu

Tags: layout, wpf-controls, dockpanel

I would like to create a screen like below using WPF.  I have a fairly good idea on how to do this but have only been using WPF for about 2 months so I would like to know from those more knowledgeable if this is the correct way to accomplish what I want.

The screen will be broken down into 3 primary usercontrols: info header, links (on the left) and info display (orange area on right containing fields of information).  I plan on using the DockPanel for the layout and then create a separate usercontrol for each area.

Is the use of DockPanel with embedded usercontrols the best way to accomplish this?

One feature I would like to incorporate is a collapsible link list as shown for 'company'.  When a user clicks on 'company' the area below company would expand and show the various options pertaining to a company (summary, info, issues, etc.).  Clicking on 'employee' would expand the employee link and collapse the 'company' link.

Is there a feature in WPF that I can utilize to handle the collapse/expand of the links?

[image: Screen Layout]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your mock-up, `DockPanel` sounds like a perfectly sensible way to go.

The side-menu sounds like an accordion control - there's one in [the WPF Toolkit on CodePlex](http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/40535), although it hasn't been updated for a while. Alternatively, you could [roll your own with a stack of `Expander` controls](http://www.rooijakkers.net/blog/post/2007/11/WPF-implementation-of-a-basic-Accordion-control.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the Expander info.  Looks like I might be able to do what I want with that and some styling.